# Django Zappa Lambda Deploy "botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException"

Tags: django, lambda, zappa

I am trying to deploy simple django application from zappa (https://romandc.com/zappa-django-guide/) I am getting the following error. Is there any permission issue or some other issue with the dev setup?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\personal\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\zappa\cli.py", line 753, in deploy
    function_name=self.lambda_name)
  File "e:\personal\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\zappa\core.py", line 1286, in get_lambda_function
    FunctionName=function_name)
  File "e:\personal\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "e:\personal\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException: An error occurred (ResourceNotFoundException) when calling the GetFunction operation: Function not found: arn:aws:lambda:ap-south-1:122866061462:function:frankie-dev

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\personal\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\zappa\cli.py", line 2778, in handle
    sys.exit(cli.handle())
  File "e:\personal\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\zappa\cli.py", line 512, in handle
    self.dispatch_command(self.command, stage)
  File "e:\personal\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\zappa\cli.py", line 549, in dispatch_command
    self.deploy(self.vargs['zip'])
  File "e:\personal\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\zappa\cli.py", line 786, in deploy
    self.lambda_arn = self.zappa.create_lambda_function(**kwargs)
  File "e:\personal\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\zappa\core.py", line 1069, in create_lambda_function
    response = self.lambda_client.create_function(**kwargs)
  File "e:\personal\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "e:\personal\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 586, in _make_api_call
    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
  File "e:\personal\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 641, in _convert_to_request_dict
    api_params, operation_model)
  File "e:\personal\envs\py3\lib\site-packages\botocore\validate.py", line 291, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "Layers", must be one of: FunctionName, Runtime, Role, Handler, Code, Description, Timeout, MemorySize, Publish, VpcConfig, DeadLetterConfig, Environment, KMSKeyArn, TracingConfig, Tags
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same error trying to deploy a Flask app using Zappa and then realized that I was using an old `botocore` package version. I changed all the package versions in my `requirements.txt` file to the ones on [zappa's github page](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/blob/master/requirements.txt)  and it fixed the issue for me!

Comment: How did you arrive at this solution, did you go through the logs or something? If so where do I find them

Comment: @Shahabaz no, more like google search results and found this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-python-runtime-errors/) which made me think that the issue could be caused by some old packages that I was using that didn't work with the latest AWS CLI? Can't say for sure.. I updated all of them to the recommended ones and then it worked. Is it still not working for you?